# PHP - Get string from Email address

Tags: php, regex

I have a email address:

```
 abc123@domain.com
```

I want to get a string "**domain.com**" by php
Please help me!

Comment: [-1, less than zero research effort](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+split+email)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `explode`, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.

```
$array = explode("@", "abc123@domain.com");
echo $array[1]; // domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to check that the email is valid before splitting it. PHP has this functionality built-in:

```
$email = "abc123@domain.com";
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $domain = array_pop(explode("@", $email));
}
```

If the email is valid, `explode` (split) the string into an array and `pop` the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `substr()`

```
echo substr($str,strpos($str,'@')+1);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/139039)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regex. just use explode like this

```
$email='abc123@domain.com';
$exploded=$pieces = explode("@", $email);
$domain=$exploded[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_array = explode("@", "abc123@domain.com");
echo $email_array[1]; // domain.com
echo $email_array[0]; //abc123
```